# AttributeName parameter cannot be null or an empty string in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have added %%=AttributeValue('CompanyName')=%% in the **Image block** Alt text field, and when I am trying to use this block in email, while generating the **Preview and Test** I am getting the following error. Even though the "CompanyName" attribute is there in the data extension.

> The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again.
> An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a ContentBlockByID function call. Function Call: ContentBlockbyID("*****") See inner exception for details.
> An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a ContentBlockByID function call. Function Call: ContentBlockById("*****") See inner exception for details.
> An error occurred when attempting to evaluate an AttributeValue function call. See inner exception for details.
> AttributeName parameter cannot be null or an empty string. Function Name: AttributeValue Parameter Name: AttributeName Parameter Ordinal: 1 Parameter Type: Text Submitted Value: ClientID: 7229*** JobID: 0 ListID: 0 BatchID: 0 SubcriberID: 1204306731 Data Source Type: CustomObject Data Source ID: adca6f83-c2f5-***-a2da-1402ec936a0d]

Answer (score 0):

You want to assign the DE value to a variable first then call it into your image tags alt attribute. Example.

%%[
Var @companyName
Set @companyName = AttributeValue('CompanyName')
]%%